# Getting Call Status with Sinch API

Tags: python, sinch

After placing a call with Sinch API using a 'ttsCallout' method, I'm trying to get the status for that call. The calls goes through, I'm receiving its 'callId'. But when it comes to requesting my call's status, I receive 200 OK as a HTTP Response and empty ('null') content.

First, I though something is wrong with my code and the way I form Authorization headers (I use Python, its requests library and basic auth), but then I tried Sinch API explorer (https://www.sinch.com/dashboard/#/api) and it shows the same output to me (see the attached screenshot). Have to notice that this code worked about a month ago, and I was able to get call status.

[image: Sinch API Explorer Screenshot]

Also, here is the code I use to communicate to Sinch API.

```
class CallNotification(Notification):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.id = ""
        self.call = self.data['call']
        self.api_url = self.call['api_url']
        self.auth = ("application:" + self.call['auth']['key'], self.call['auth']['secret'])
        self.status = {'http': "new", 'result': "none", 'reason': "none"}

    def send(self):
        request_url = self.api_url + "/callouts"
        request = requests.post(request_url,
                                auth=self.auth,
                                json={
                                        'method': "ttsCallout",
                                        'ttsCallout':  {
                                                        'cli': "private",
                                                        'destination': {
                                                                         'type': "number",
                                                                        'endpoint': self.call['to']
                                                                   },
                                                        'domain': "pstn",
                                                        'custom': "customData",
                                                        'locale': "en-US",
                                                        'text': self.call['message']
                                                        }
                                     },
                                headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
        self.id = json.loads(request.content)['callId']
        self.status['http'] = request.reason
        return self.status['http']

   def getstatus(self):
        if not self.status['http'] == "new":
            request_url = self.api_url + "/calls/id/" + self.id
            request = requests.get(request_url,
                                   auth=self.auth,
                                   headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})

            try:
                self.status['result'] = json.loads(request.content)['result']
            except TypeError:
                self.status['result'] = "Sent/Unknown"
        return self.status['result']
```

Am I doing something wrong? What do I do to get status for a placed call?